# Does Fourier cosine series converge in $L^2$ sense?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0, 0<x<1\\ 1, 1<x<3 \end{cases}$

**We have that its Fourier cosine series is given by 
$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0, 0<x<1\\ \frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3}), 1<x<3 \end{cases}$.
Does it converge to $\phi$ in the $L^2$ sense? Why?**

We have that if  $0<x<1$, then $\phi(x)$ converges to zero in $L^2$
sense.

If $1<x<3,$ then we should verify that $$\displaystyle\int_1^3\left\vert 1-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(m\pi/3)}{m}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3}) \right\vert^2dx\to 0 \text{ when } m\to\infty\\ \iff\displaystyle\int_1^3\left\vert \frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(m\pi/3)}{m}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3}) \right\vert^2dx\to 0 \text{ when } m\to\infty$$

Am I correct so far ?

Any hint please on how should I continue from here?

---

**edit:** I had a typo in the definition of Fourier series, it's 2/3 instead of 4/3. Sorry.

**edit 2:** I found the following result which is equivalent to prove $L^2$ convergence. If $\{x_n\}$ are the eigenfunctions of symmetric boundary conditions of the problem and $\vert f\vert$ is finite, then $\Vert f-\sum{A_nx_n}\Vert\to0$ when  $N\to\infty$

The problem is I just have the series and not a problem with boundary conditions,etc.

What  do I do then ?? :(

Comment: Instead of looking at your specific problem, just look into what the closed linear span of the cosines of half-integer frequency is.

Comment: @Ian hmm I don't get it, what's the idea? 'closed linear span' I've never heard of it before.

Comment: Instead of "analysis", try to use a more specific name (as suggested in the [tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info)). See also some discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/why-is-the-tag-analysis-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of this question is strange. You wrote "We have that its Fourier cosine series is given by

$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0, 0<x<1\\ \frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3}), 1<x<3"\end{cases}$$

Why do you set $\phi$ equal to this, and why do you have cases? Why not just write that the Fourier cosine series of $\phi$ on $[0,3]$ is

$$\tag 1 \frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3})?$$

The basic question appears to be: Does $(1)$ converge to $\phi$ in $L^2[0,3]?$ The answer is yes. Now you wrote that this series, restricted to $[0,1],$ converges to $0$ in $L^2[0,1],$ but I'm not sure where you're getting that from.

The very well known general result here is this: Suppose $f\in L^2[0,T].$ Define the Fourier cosine coefficients $c_n$ of $f$ as follows:

$$c_0 = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(x),\,\,c_n=\frac{2}{T}\int_0^T f(x)\cos(n\pi x/T)\, dx,\,\, n=1,2,\dots $$

Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n\cos(n\pi x/T)$ converges to $f$ in the $L^2[0,T]$ norm. I.e.,

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\,\int_0^T |f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_n\cos(n\pi x/T)|^2\, dx =0.$$

That proves the answer to your question is yes. Are you familiar with the general result?

Comment: To your 1st question: because $\phi(x)$ is defined by parts, so I computed its Fourieer series by parts as well. I didn't know it can be written as you did, but I have to say it doesn't convince me 100% because $\phi$ is not defined at $x=1$ and with $[0,3]$ you are saying that it's defined at $x=1$.

Comment: To your 2nd question: Why are you considering the closed interval [0,3] ? Shouldn't be treated in cases? like I did?

Comment: To your 3rd question: Not exactly like that, but it looks like the definition that I have in my notes about convergence in $L^2$ sense, and if you look at my attempt I already made the substitutions in the integral. Now I just need a magic trick to calculate it :)

Comment: However my attempt might be all wrong if we now consider your interval $[0,3]$

Comment: I said the series goes to zero in $(0,1)$ because the series is already zero in that interval :) according to the definition that I wrote.

Comment: With $L^2$ convergence there is no need to worry about the values of $\phi$ at a few points. It also doesn't matter if the interval is $(0,3)$ or $[0,3];$ or it simply doesn't matter. I repeat: The series

$$\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3})$$

converges to $\phi$ in $L^2[0,3]$ from the general $L^2$ result I mentioned.

Comment: oh ok, so I just state the general result that you wrote and then I should write: 'hence the serie $\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin(m\pi/3)}{m\pi}\cos(\frac{m\pi x}{3})$ converge to...' ?

Comment: Well, it's not clear to me what your background is, what course this is, why you need this result, etc. But I will say the basic $L^2$ result I gave is pretty standard. It's easier than many of the pointwise convergence results.

Comment: It's a Fourier analysis course. Is this a result from measure theory or functional anlysis or from where?. At first I though I had to compute the integral explicitly but I guess it's not really necessary with the result that you stated.

Comment: It's called Parseval's theorem. You can find this in Rudin PMA for example. There he proves two versions, one for Rieman integrable functions (your $\phi$ is such) and later for $L^2$ functions.